# regularity of Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

This problem is from $Spectral \ Theory \ and \ its \ Applications,\ Bernard\ Helffer, \ Page \ 37$. 
It says that if $u \in H^1(\mathbf{R^m}), x_j u \in L^2(\mathbf{R^m}),(-\Delta+\vert x \vert^2+1 )u \in L^2(\mathbf{R^m}) $ then \begin{equation}
u\in B^2(\mathbf{R^m}) :=\lbrace u\in H^2(\mathbf{R^m}): x^{\alpha} u \in L^2(\mathbf{R^m}),\forall \alpha,s.t.\vert \alpha \vert \leq 2 \rbrace
\end{equation}
The book ssys it needs a regularity theorem based on the method of differential quotients, but there are no details. And I really want to know how it works. I've tried to prove this when $m=1$, but it seems not easy. Now I have an idea:

Show that if \begin{equation}
(\pm\frac{d}{dx}+x)f \in L^2, f \in L^2,\ then \ xf \in L^2 
\end{equation}
Is this helpful?

Okay, now a $2010$ version of this book says that this differential method can be find in $Non-Homogeneous \ Boundary \ Value \ Problems \ and \ Applications,\ Lions\ and\ Magenes$. But where can I find this book?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lions+and+magenes